# R markdown add chart and text to pane

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create an R markdown page which includes in the panes both a chart and some supporting text, the code I am using to do this is as below

````
    ---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    
     table2<- botor::s3_read("s3://alpha-em-emmi-reports/Nick_Files/Untagged/Table2.csv", read.csv)
    
    ```      
     column{}
        -------------------------------------
    ### Slide 1. Number and proportion(%) of dividuals
    
    -   The chart below shows how the the makeup of the individuals has varied over the last 12 months
    -   The proportion of individuals who has increased by 11 percentage points from 44% in January 2022 to 55% in December 2022, whereas the proportion has decreased by five percentage points from 44% to 3%
    -   Excludes alcohol and specials
    -  Data is dummy
    
    ```{r}
      table3 %>% 
        plot_ly(labels=~Reason_Category,values=~sum) %>% 
        add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>% 
        layout(title = "",  showlegend =TRUE,
               xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
               yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE))
    
    
    ```
## Column {data-width="350"}

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```
````

However I cannot get the chart and text/bullets to fit the page, and the bottom of the chart is cut off, and my dashboard looks something like this:-

[image]

Can anyone advise on how i can reduce size of chart to ensure everything fits within the pane

Thanks

Nick